# Find the signature of a reflection.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products, orthogonality, reflection

I am doing some self-study and I have this task:

Show that the signature of the following mapping, the reflection about the hyperplane $a^{\perp}$, given by

$S_a(v) = v - 2\frac{<v,a>}{<a,a>}a$

is (n-1,1,0), where a is an arbitrary nonzero vector.

I would know how to find the eigenvalues of this mapping if I had a matrix on hand, but I am not sure how I would do it this way. Should I just find the representative matrix of this mapping and go with it?

Comment: What is your definition of the signature of a linear map? A reflection is a symmetry about a hyperplane, so you know instantly its diagonalization.

Comment: I am new to this. Can you explain this fact more deeply? Again, I am self-studying. Thank you.

Comment: Again, please, what is your definition of the signature of a linear map? What do you mean by "the signature of $S_a$ is (n-1,1,0)"? I only know the notion of signature of a real quadratic form.

Comment: It has n-1 positive eigenvalues, 1 negative eigenvalue, and 0 eigenvalues equal to 0. And n is of course the dimension of the vector space we are dealing with, so it's the number of entries in a and v.

Answer (score 2):

A [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(mathematics)#Reflection_through_a_hyperplane_in_n_dimensions) is a special case of linear involution, with a hyperplane as subspace of fixed vectors: $S_a(v)=v\iff v\perp a$ and $S_a(v)=-v\iff v\in\operatorname{span}(a)$.

More generally (and even on an infinite dimensional space), a [linear involution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)#Linear_algebra) has two complementary eigenspaces, associated with the eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: I understand it now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Under the reflection $a\to -a$,  $a^{\perp}$ is invariant. In any basis with this split $e_1=a, e_{2\dots n} \in a^{\perp}$, the signature is evident.